# Integrating socket.io into a REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, express, ionic-framework, socket.io

I'm trying to create a platform using angularjs (web), ionic (mobile) and expressjs (backend), the communication through REST. Angular and Node has differents servers.

```
.-----------.      .----------.      .-----------.
|  SERVER A |      |          |      |  SERVER B |
|  ANGULAR  | <--> |   REST   | <--> |    NODE   |
| PORT 3300 |      |          |      | PORT 3000 |
'-----------'      '----------'      '-----------'
```

The problem for me, is how to integrate socket.io in angular (or ionic) to communicate with the backend (for the chat part).
All examples that i see, they return an html page in the response. for example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

What I want exactly, is how to send a messages from front to backend (for example to `localhost:3000/users/chat` knowing that i'm runing my angular project on `localhost:3300`), how to handle that messages from server, and how to response to them using socket.io

Comment: Does the angular server run on the same machine as the node server?

Comment: Currently yes (seen i'm in the development phase)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Your web page can just make a socket.io connection to any host it wants to and then have an open socket with that host over which is can send/receive messages.  socket.io, by itself, has nothing to do with a REST API.  A REST API call could trigger messages to be sent via your socket.io connection if desired or a socket.io message might change server state which could affect future REST API results, but that's about as connected as the two might be.

Comment: what's unclear exactly ?

Comment: I already have a REST API, and I want to include socket.io to add chat option to my platform (don't think that make my question 'unclear' to vote down ;) )

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The socket.io documentation shows exactly how to integrate socket.io with an Express server.  Still don't know what you're asking beyond what the socket.io documentation shows.  If you want help here, you need to ask a much more specific question and show relevant portions of your code and show what you tried.  socket.io shares the Express server.  See the socket.io doc for how to use it with Express.

Comment: The problem is, for example how to use it with ionic. As I mentionned, in all example, they return a static page res.sendfile('index.html');` that can be useful in a web application that's running on the same server. My question is HOW TO USE SOCKET.IO WHEN WE HAVE SEPARATE SERVERS OR USING HYBRIDE MOBILE APPS?